# 1passwordでMFA認証したいのですが、このurlの①がでないんですが、どうすればいいでしょうか？

Tags: aws

1passwordでMFA認証したいのですが、このurlの①がでないんですが、どうすればいいでしょうか？
環境はwindows10です。

https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/1password-mfa/

[image: ①のQRを読み込むマークがでてこない]

Comment: aws以外のサイトであれば①が表示されるのでしょうか？ Yesならawsが関連する問題、 Noならサイトに関係なく1passwordの問題となり、質問の趣旨が変わってくると思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

chromeのアドオンだとQRコードが表示されなかったが、1passwordのデスクトップアプリのほうであればQRコードが表示され、問題が解消された。